# Locate schema.xml in Solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, cloud9-ide, pysolr

I have installed django-haystack and pysolr. I don't get any errors so I think I've installed it correctly. I have called `build_solr_schema` and I now have a xml output. I am going to insert this xml output in `schema.xml` but I can't locate it.

I'm using Cloud9 so it's not that obvious where to look.

Hope someone has solved this issue before me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install `Solr`?

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html

`Schema.xml` puts in solr folder.